# How can I integrate Identity Server 4 two-factor authentication with an app like Google Authenticator?

Tags: c#, asp.net, identityserver4, two-factor-authentication, google-authenticator

I've set up the [Identity Server 4 sample which uses AspNetIdentity and Entity Framework](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/master/samples/Quickstarts/9_Combined_AspId_and_EFStorage). This includes a UI to associate an authenticator app with a signed-in account. It looks like this:

[image]

To test this out I downloaded the Google Authenticator app, added an account to it using the key provided, then submitted the verification code.

This hits the `EnableAuthenticator` action inside `ManageController`, calling `_userManager.VerifyTwoFactorTokenAsync`. But this always returns false. I assume therefore that I need to register a service that integrates with Google Authenticator and verifies the token. But I can't find anywhere on the web that will help me with this. Are you able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Not posting an answer because I'm not familiar with that specific 2FA system, but that falls under the heading of "UI" which means Identity Server doesn't get involved. You'll have to build that whole flow as part of your own login UI.

Comment: The link in your question returns a 404.
Can you update it or tell me where I can find the code for your 2FA solution?

Comment: @KarlGjertsen in case this is still relevant to you, i have edited the post with an updated link: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/master/samples/Quickstarts/9_Combined_AspId_and_EFStorage